# find first non-blank column in visual selection

Tags: visual-mode, whitespace, linewise-visual

If I select all of these lines in linewise-visual mode

```
    hi
    there
  how
    do
    you
       do
```

How can I get the column number of the first non-blank character from the left? I.e. the minimum column arrived at after running `^` on every line,

in this case it should return `3` because the `h` in `how` is in the third column

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: @romainl `:indent` but it treats tabs as more than 1 col

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seem to have arrived at a beautiful, obvious, succinct, and readable answer for this trivial task:

```
min(map(range(line("'<"), line("'>")), "match(getline(v:val), \"\\\\S\")"))
```